# Is SCRUM Methodology a good technique to go with in crucial deadline project?

Tags: scrum, development-methodologies, sdlc

I am just join a firm and they are working in a (their called) SCRUM methodology, They have very sharp deadline and the project development doesnt seems to have any direction or neither it is looking like (This is what we want.) I am developing a module which doesnt have Database, neither I have any information which needs to linked to this module, the people who are linked to the modules and messed up with their own work because which I am not able to get their support in it.

Now could anyone suggest me that is this the good way to go ahead in this methodology, which doesnt contain any DB table for to be developed module?

Please Suggest Something..

Thanks

Comment: Actually Scrum is a good way to go. AS LONG AS they implement it correctly. One of the good thing Scrum have is daily standup, where The meetings timeboxed to 5–15 minutes and are held standing up to remind people to keep the meeting short and to the point.

Comment: I have to have some Output at the end of the day.. else it is just a waste of time

Comment: Whether your code uses a database or not has nothing to do with the methodology.

Comment: But at core level it makes sense, afterall these all entities make us to follow the methodology

Comment: @OM The Eternity : You should have output at the end of the day. The output can be something like "my task is done 50%, compared to 40% yesterday."

Comment: why do you think you need a database anyway?

Comment: @Rudy: Do not report percent done, but estimated time to completion. Otherwise you'll see half of the task stuck at 90% :o) If you extend the time, say why (I found this and this problem).

Comment: Just figure out for yourself what Scrum is and you'll see it doesn't even remotely resemble the organization you describe. Nor do any of your problems have anything to do with Scrum, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your company actually uses SCRUM, then the project has a SCRUM Master whose main job it is to remove any obstacles the team members see in their progress. If you believe the lack of a database hinders your work, discuss it with the SCRUM Master.

I see three possibilities:

- As a new team member, you're unused to the way things are done in this company. Perhaps the SCRUM Master can give you some explanations after which you'll understand better
- The work is disorganized and the SCRUM Master is not doing his job properly. Perhaps he does not have the time due to other duties. You should discuss this with management, but (especially as a new employee) be very polite and focus on the fact that there is a problem that needs to be solved, not on assigning blame.
- The project does not have a SCRUM Master. The company is not, in fact, using SCRUM, no matter what they claim.

Answer (score 8):

Scrum is all about iterative releases, showing the user what they are getting before they get it, letting them prioritise the goals. This is perfect when your deadline is tight and the project seems directionless. It means that the customer can see the constant development (rather than it being a black box which churns out a useless product just before the deadline) and direct which parts are most important for that deadline to be considered a success.

As to whether your module has a database or not, that's not really relevant to the question. But if you code it well, it shouldn't matter. Use a file-based storage or even hardcode the data while demoing to the user, but keep that code well abstracted from the real logic. When the database is ready, you should be able to just switch out that part of the code easily.

A bit of advice: write unit tests for the bones of your module. This will show you quickly how to abstract data layers from logic.

Comment: Cool Explanation @pdr thanks for the explanation....

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, this doesn't sound like Scrum problem to me, but rather lack of proper engineering. Scrum process was probably put in place to "fix" things, but they can't even do that one properly. Well the bad news is, any methodology will not work without craftsmanship.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are in an environment that is not proper scrum.

> the project development doesnt seems to have any direction or neither it is looking like (This is what we want.)

In Scrum, you are supposed to have a "Product Owner", who defines what the product is supposed to do, and is available to answer detailed questions about how it should work. If you have no direction, your Product Owner is either missing, or not doing their job.

> I am developing a module which doesn't have a Database, neither do I have any information which needs to linked to this module, the people who are linked to the modules and messed up with their own work because which I am not able to get their support in it.

While lack of a *database* is not, in and of itself an issue, your question reveals some serious issues in your company's Scrum implementation. In Scrum, stories should be about functionality, and should be developed in "vertical slices", adding whatever infrastructure is needed to enable the functionality. If you have no database, and no support on other modules that you are supposed to link to, it sounds to me like the project has been sliced "horizontally". An app developed using Scrum should start very thin, and fatten up with features.